# Returning NAN for each value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I'm trying to return a list of objects from my Array, but instead I'm returning three NAN values.

```
var books = [];

function Book(title, author, alreadyRead){

    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.alreadyRead = alreadyRead

}

function addBook(title, author, alreadyRead){
    var b = new Book(title, author, alreadyRead);
    books.push(b);
}

addBook("The Hunger Games", "Suzannee Collins", true);
addBook("The Bible", "Various Authors", true);
addBook("The Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", false);

function printBooks(books){
    let arrayLength = books.length 

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        console.log(books.title + books.author);
    }
 }


 printBooks(books);
```

I'm not too sure what's happening, so can anyone illuminate this for me?

Comment: `books.title + books.author` - the variable `books` is the *array*, so you're trying to get the property `title` and property `author` of an array object then sum them together. `undefined + undefined` is `NaN`. You want `books[i].title + books[i].author`

Comment: `console.log(books[i].title + books[i].author)` — you have the index variable, you just need to use it

Answer (score 2):

In `printBooks` function, you iterate with a `for` over the book properties which means that you must specify the book number, which is `i` -> will be `book[1].title = "The Hunger Games"` and so on

> I'm trying to return a list of objects from my Array

In your function you only print them, is this what you want?

```js
var books = [];

function Book(title, author, alreadyRead) {

  this.title = title
  this.author = author
  this.alreadyRead = alreadyRead

}

function addBook(title, author, alreadyRead) {
  var b = new Book(title, author, alreadyRead);
  books.push(b);
}

addBook("The Hunger Games", "Suzannee Collins", true);
addBook("The Bible", "Various Authors", true);
addBook("The Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", false);

function printBooks(books) {
  let arrayLength = books.length

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(books[i].title + books[i].author);
  }
}


printBooks(books);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the index [i] in for loop

```
function printBooks(books){
    let arrayLength = books.length 

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        console.log(books[i].title + books[i].author);
    }
 }
```